# Apple Watch Connectivity framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, xcode7

Previously, before WatchOS 2 it was very hard for your apple watch and iPhone to communicate but with WatchOS 2 and the new `Watch Connectivity`framework it seems to have improved a lot.

What I am wondering is that with this new framework, is there an easy way for me to run a function on the parent app on the iPhone by clicking a button on the apple watch. Before you would have to use wormhole and it was very confusing.

Basically all I want is to press a button on my watch, and it'll run a line of code on my iPhone!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sendMessage API

1) Call `sendMessage` method by clicking a button on the apple watch.

```
WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(applicationDict,
   replyHandler: { ([String : AnyObject]) → Void in
      // Handle reply
   })
   errorHandler: { (NSError) → Void in
      // Handle error
});
```

2) `didReceiveMessage` method is called in your iPhone

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    // send data to Apple Watch
    replyHandler(["retrievedData" : data])
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Apple WCSession you can find all the necessary to create a direct message from a device to the other.

Answer (score 0):

For this you would want to use the WCSession's sendMessage API which will wake the iOS app up if necessary to deliver the message